# Making ExpressJs recognise base path

Tags: node.js, express

I have built an small nodejs app using express. Everything works fine on my local machine & the app runs good when I point my browser to `http://localhost:3000`

But now I am planning to host this app on one of the domain, Lets say `http://example.org` which is running on nginx & its a php code

But how do I make my express app to properly run the app on `example.org/nodeapp` ?
Currently, it is considering the `example.org` as base url of my app & hence throws 404 as it searches for `nodeapp` in my routes. It should ideally consider `example.org/nodeapp` as baseurl.

In my server block config, I have following code

```
listen 80;

server_name your-domain.com;

location /nodeapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have nginx rewrite the url by adding something like `rewrite ^/nodeapp/(.*) /$1 break;`